# Premake5 gmake target always doing full rebuild

Tags: premake

I've been using (and been pretty happy with) premake4/5 with Visual Studio. Recently I started moving my project to other platforms, and noticed that contrary to compiling in VS, the gmake target generated Makefiles, under Windows with clang, ALWAYS do a full rebuild of all projects, even if only the final "main" C++ file has been changed. Contrary to that GCC does properly only rebuild the changed files.

Am I doing something wrong? Is that the intended behavior? Any hints on what could be wrong with my premake files?

Comment: Happy to help, but you'll need to provide a *simple* Premake5 script example that demonstrates the problem so we can help debug.